# Batch-export org-mode subtree by headline?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

## Pretext

I am using the emacs batch mode to script the export of `.org` files to LaTeX via a `Makefile`, and I am aware of some of the customization options that exist in that regard.

For example, I can (under Emacs 25.2.2 with org-mode 9.1.11) successfully use the command

```
emacs my.org --batch --eval "(org-latex-export-to-latex nil nil nil t)" --kill
```

to export *only the body* (via the fourth argument set to `t`) of `my.org` file to `my.tex`. The arguments of `org-latex-export-to-latex` are described at https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/master/lisp/ox-latex.el#L3588.

## Problem description

I am now looking for a possibility to batch-export *a specific subtree* from an `.org` file. In other words, while I have already managed to script the 'body-only' `C-e C-b` option of a manual org-mode export, I am now trying to also automate its `C-e C-s` option.

This raises the question of how to identify the desired subtree to-be-exported.

## Not quite what I want: Export by `ID` via `.el` script

The exact same problem that I am describing is also formulated at

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-02/msg00133.html

The responses suggest to export a section by its `ID` property and include pointers to

- https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/testing/lisp/test-ob.el
- https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/testing/examples/babel.org

for according emacs-lisp code, as well as a more specific emacs-lisp code example, which I can successfully get to export a specific section by its `CUSTOM_ID` property.

However, **this solution has the following flaws**:

1. It includes the heading of the section identified by `CUSTOM_ID`, whereas a subtree exported manually via `C-e C-s` contains only the *content* of the exported section (which is what I want).
2. It requires me to specify `CUSTOM_ID`s, whereas I am hoping to identify the subtree to-be-exported by the text of its headline.
3. It requires emacs-lisp code. :)

## Perhaps a better solution: 2nd argument of `org-latex-export-to-latex`?

The code for `org-latex-export-to-latex` at https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/master/lisp/ox-latex.el#L3575 shows that its second argument relates to the export of subtrees, and I am wondering whether it can be used to achieve my goals outlined above.

The comment at https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/master/lisp/ox-latex.el#L3588 says:

> When optional argument SUBTREEP is non-nil, export the sub-tree at
>   point, extracting information from the headline properties first.

However, the code comment above to me **raises the following questions**:

- What does "at point" mean?
- How exactly would it "extract information from the headline properties"
- What meaningful non-nil values can I set this option to?

I would appreciate examples of how the second argument of `org-latex-export-to-latex` can be used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
emacs my.org --batch --eval \
      "(progn (re-search-forward \"CUSTOM_ID: ${FOO}\") \
              (org-latex-export-to-latex nil t nil t))"
```

[ Note: 100% untested ]

Comment: The search should include the headline (see point 2). Looks good otherwise. [Related](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48513/how-can-i-export-an-org-subtree-to-html-from-the-command-line/48520#48520).