# How can I export an Org subtree to HTML from the command line?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a list of links that I store in a subtree in an org file. Is there a way to export this to an HTML file using the command line? I figure it's something like `emacsclient --eval ...` with an elisp command for exporting that header, but I'm not sure how best to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `org-id` (there are, of course, other ways of finding a subtree in the buffer).

```
emacsclient -e "(progn (find-file \"$1\") \
                       (org-id-goto \"$2\") \
                       (org-html-export-to-html nil t))"
```

First you have to create an ID for the entry you want to export using `org-id-get-create` and then:

```
$ htmlexport '~/file.org' 'd00d2d9e-8e48-4c60-898e-7b91b12302cf'`
```